# Using Pixi.js to change the height of a div through code fails

Tags: javascript, properties, pixi.js

For some reason, when I change the height of my containerobject in Pixi.js the "wrong" property is changed. When I do it through console it works.

[image]

As you can see in the image, the "height" property exists 2 times. One times "greyed out", one time "normal". Also, the "normal" version has an indent but is not a property of a child.

Change height through code -> changes "normal" version and has no effect

Change height through console -> changes "greyed out" version and has effect on the height of the Pixi container

Comment: Seems like the grayed out height property is somehow implicit, taken from the object with the highest hit on the Y axis, the not grayed out one is the one set by the user. But somehow sometimes you are able to set the grayed out one through console.